# Search from NSArray using Predicate

Tags: ios, iphone, nsarray, nspredicate

my current array looks like below. i create this array format for sectionIndex table. so i can search from array and display search text using index table.

```
arrContent = (
    {
    key = A;
    value =         (
        Ac,
        Acting
    );
},
    {
    key = B;
    value =         (
        Basketball,
        Baseball
    );
},
    {
    key = C;
    value =         (
        Cat
    );
}
    {
    key = P;
    value =         (
        Panda,
        Peacock
    );
}
)
```

My Search code looks like below. and it is working fine.

```
-(void)searchText:(NSString *) text
{
[arrSearch removeAllObjects];
for (int i = 0; i < [arrContent count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arrFind = arrContent[i][@"value"];
    for (int j = 0; j < [arrFind count]; j++)
    {
        NSString *str = arrFind[j];
        // containsString: method find my string if its available within range
        if ([str containsString:text])
            [temp addObject:str];
    }

    if ([temp count])
    {
        [arrSearch addObject:@{@"key":arrContent[i][@"key"],@"value":temp}];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Search : %@",text);
NSLog(@"arrSearch : %@",arrSearch);
}
```

i got output like below. which is correct.

```
Search : ac
arrSearch : (
    {
    key = A;
    value =         (
        Ac,
        Acting
    );
},
    {
    key = P;
    value =         (
        Peacock
    );
}
)
```

I just want to ask that if is there any better way to search and get same output using **NSPredicate**  because for loop will take time when lots of data.

Help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built in function on NSArray like this...

```
- (NSArray *)filterArrayUsingText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSMutableArray *filteredWordArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in yourWordArray) {
        NSArray *filteredWords = [self filterWordsFromArray:dictionary[@"value"] usingText:text];

        if (filteredWords) {
            [filteredWordArray addObject:@{@"key":dictionary[@"key"], @"value", filteredWords}];
        }
    }

    return filteredWordArray;
}

- (NSArray *)filterWordsFromArray:(NSArray *)wordArray usingText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(NSString *theWord, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [theWord containsString:text];
    }];

    NSArray *filteredArray = [wordArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    return filteredArray.count == 0 ? nil : filteredArray;
}
```

Also, make sure to use modern Obj-C syntax.

Also, the way the data is stored is a bit broken. For key/value pairs you don't store `Key` and `Value`.

You would store like this...

```
{
    A: (Ac,
        Acting),
    B: (Basketball,
        Baseball),
    C: (Cat),
    P: (Panda,
        Peacock)
}
```

Comment: No if i search "Ac" then i want only text which contains "ac" in value  array.

Comment: @Chinttu-RoxeN-Ramani edited. Again though. Use updated syntax and make sure your data is stored properly. At the moment it isn't.

Comment: can you please tell me how to sort all this keys in ascending order because i've to show this all data in table using section. like Section = "A" and row's are array index. maybe i have to sort keys and then add object in array. right?

Comment: Sorting the array is a different question. However, it's one that has been answered hundreds of times on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: hehe i knw. maybe you are not understanding what i'm trying to say. i knw we can sort using NSSortDescriptor. leave it i'll do that. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Chinttu-RoxeN-Ramani I'd use a sort descriptor with a block and return `[obj1[@"key"] compare:objj2[@"key"]];` easy and fast :D remember to accept if it has answered your problem :D

Comment: this much help is really appreciated thanks buddy :)