# Search from Nested NSArray from NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a nested `NSArray`.

```
Array1=[@"Ali",@"Ahmed"]; 
Array2=[@"Bilal",@"Qasim"]; 
Array3=[Array1,Array2];
```

How can I search character by character using NSPredicate?
What I'm doing is

```
NSPredicate *pred = ["SELF Contains [c] %@", searchCharacter];
```

Tried replacing 'Contains' by word '`MATCH`' but I didn't give me any results.
Is that possible to do search from nested array by predicate as I'm new to iOS and little confused. Any help will be appreciated!

I have found some answers here [Search from NSArray using Predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739083/search-from-nsarray-using-predicate) but the array structure was different in that case.

Comment: I did not have any key value and dictionary used.

Comment: This would be much easier if you _didn't_ use NSPredicate. Is there a good reason why you have to?

Comment: If you don't need the predicate with format as found in the dup, you can use predicate with block as an alternative, or (even more simply) nested fast enumeration.